# target, image[0] in datasets sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

what is the use of `target`and `image[0]` method in digits datasets ?

```
from sklearn import datasets   
digits = datasets.load_digits()
digits.target
digits.images[0]
```

prints

```
array([0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9, 8])

array([[  0.,   0.,   5.,  13.,   9.,   1.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  13.,  15.,  10.,  15.,   5.,   0.],
       [  0.,   3.,  15.,   2.,   0.,  11.,   8.,   0.],
       [  0.,   4.,  12.,   0.,   0.,   8.,   8.,   0.],
       [  0.,   5.,   8.,   0.,   0.,   9.,   8.,   0.],
       [  0.,   4.,  11.,   0.,   1.,  12.,   7.,   0.],
       [  0.,   2.,  14.,   5.,  10.,  12.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   6.,  13.,  10.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

Comment: docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html

Answer (score 1):

`target` return a vector where each value corresponds to the label of each image of the data set: digit between 0 to 9.

`image[0]` corresponds to the first image encoded as a matrix of size (8,8).